# MPICH - enable debugging prints from `MPIU_DBG_PRINTF()`

Tags: mpich

What is right order of configuring and running MPICH2 or MPICH-3 to enable debugging prints, embedded to code with `MPIU_DBG_PRINTF()`. I already used `--enable-g=dbg,mem,log` configure option, and set environment variable `MPICH_DBG_OUTPUT` to `stdout` but still have no debug prints from the `examples/cpi` runs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you might need to set a few extra environment variables:

- MPICH_DBG_LEVEL to VERBOSE
- MPICH_DBG_CLASS to ALL

For example:

```
mpiexec -n 2 -env MPICH_DBG_OUTPUT VERBOSE \
    -env MPICH_DBG_CLASS ALL \
    -env MPICH_DBG_FILENAME "dbg-%w-%d.log" ./examples/cpi
```

The wiki has some more information about the other things you can do with the MPICH debugging facility:

https://wiki.mpich.org/mpich/index.php/Debug_Event_Logging

Comment: Rob, thank you! Please, add `MPICH_DBG_CLASS=ALL` env setting to your answer, it was needed too. Now I use `mpiexec -n 2 -env MPICH_DBG_OUTPUT VERBOSE -env MPICH_DBG_CLASS ALL -env MPICH_DBG_FILENAME "dbg-%w-%d.log"  ./examples/cpi` to get the debugging logs.

Comment: Good suggestion, and good question.  I've ended up in similar situations and gone crazy wondering why I could not get debugging output.